# what is the meaning of iteration in for loop?

Tags: java

If the task is to create 20 iterations.

in the loop statement, should I write :
i<=20 or i<20  ?

Comment: Depends on what number `i` starts from.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) { }` will run exactly one time because at the second iteration, `i < 1` is false.

Comment: ...and `for(int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) { }` will run exactly one time too, as at the second iteration `i = 2` so `i <= 1` is false.

Comment: one iteration through a loop means exactly what you would think... you executed the code in the loop one time

Comment: If its an exercise, I would suggest you should try both and see which one prints 20 and why.

Comment: Why not professor explain "iterations" in the class before assigning the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what values you choose to start with (**initial value**), what **condition** you are putting and what is your **change criteria** as shown in a typical `for` loop given below

```
for(initial value;condition;change criteria)
```

e.g.
all of the following loops will run for 20 times

```
for (int i=0;i<20;i++){
    //Some logic
}

for (int i=1;i<=20;i++){
    //Some logic
}

for (int i=1;i<21;i++){
    //Some logic
}

for (int i=0;i<=19;i++){
    //Some logic
}

//Start i with 2 and increase it by 2 after every iteration until it reaches 40
for (int i=2;i<=40;i+=2){
    //Some logic
}

//Start i with 20 and decrease it by 1 after every iteration until it reaches 1
for (int i=20;i>0;i--){
    //Some logic
}

//Start i with 40 and decrease it by 2 after every iteration until it reaches 2
for (int i=40;i>=2;i-=2){
    //Some logic
}
```

...and so on. There can be infinite number of ways in which you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

**Iteration** is the repetition of a  computational procedure applied to the result of a previous one, as it says in WikiPedia.

So... Every iteration is a cicle turn in the For Loop, and the way you should write it depends of what number `i` starts from, for example:

```
for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
```

Is going to count 20 times, counting from 0 no 19, because 19 is the last number less than 20.

If you want to use `i<=20` you should star `i` from 1, because is going to count 20 times until 20, because 20 is equal to 20 so it will be

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
```

In conclusion, when you use `i<=20`, you are saying that you want the iterations from `i=0` until it became a 20, because  20 is **less or equal to** 20. 
If you use `i<20`, you down want to count the 20, because 20 **is not less than** 20.